# If $\mathbb EX=0$ and $\mathbb E|X| < \infty $ implies finite Variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I think, I am  totally wrong, but
if $\mathbb E|X|$ is finite then,

$$\text{Var}|X|=\mathbb E|X^{2}|- (\mathbb E(X))^{2}=\mathbb E|X^{2}|< \infty$$
Considering $\mathbb E|X|< \infty$ implies $\mathbb E|X^{2}|<\infty$.

Comment: That last sentence is where you messed up.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you asking for a proof of the statement? Or merely if the statement is true?

Comment: No, $E|X| < \infty$ does not imply $E|X^2| < \infty$. Think about it: If the domain of $X$ is $[1,\infty[$, then the terms in the second integral have a square in them, so they grow much faster: $\int_{1}^\infty x f(x)dx \le \int_{1}^\infty x^2 f(x)dx$. So if the left side is finite, the right side could still easily be $\infty$. If you'd like an example, see the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with any $\alpha \in ]1,2]$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if the $k$th moment is finite, the moment of order $k+1$ need not be finite.  For instance, the $t$ distribution with $k>1$ degrees of freedom has moments of order $1,2,...,k-1$ while moments of order $k$ and above do not exist.